# Microsoft Azure: 'New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'location'

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I'm a beginner at Microsoft Azure so please bear with me. I'm following [this](https://thesleepyadmins.com/2022/04/05/deploy-azure-resource-using-bicep-template-and-powershell/) tutorial on deploying bicep templates with parameters, my bicep file is the exact same as the one in the tutorial. However, when I attempt to deploy it I get the following error

`New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'location'.`

The location parameter definitely exists. I'm deploying with the following command:

`New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName ResourceGroup -TemplateFile c:\Users\Name\Desktop\files\azure\testing\test.bicep -location region -storagename storageaccountname -storagetype Standard_LRS -WhatIf`

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the tutorial contains an error. In the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azresourcegroupdeployment?view=azps-8.1.0&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203), there is ***no*** `location` parameter in the `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment` cmdlet.

Also, you have already specified a resource group, and the resources you describe with bicep contain a location. So the location parameter makes no sense here - just leave it out!

Note that you can also deploy your bicep files using the Azure CLI. See [Deploy local Bicep file](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/deploy-cli?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203#deploy-local-bicep-file)

Answer (score 1):

A way to not have to put in the location for a resource if you have all resources in the same location is to make use of

[image]

[image]

So as long as you have run this command, it will apply for all bicep files you run with it configured as such:

[image]

This means you don't need to provide it with every CLI command for bicep.

I followed this tutorial series and found it fantastic:

[Beginner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/paths/fundamentals-bicep/)

[Intermediate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/paths/intermediate-bicep/)

[Advanced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/paths/advanced-bicep/)

Answer (score 0):

What the `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment` command allows you to do is supply parameter values via PowerShell params.  So while the command has its own parameters and `location` is not one of them, any extra parameters supplied to the command are passed as template parameters.  If the template does not have a parameter named `location` (for example) - you'll see that error.

That error is usually pretty accurate, so the template may very well not have a parameter named `location`.  Check to make sure the file `c:\Users\Name\Desktop\files\azure\testing\test.bicep` has a location param, and that you've saved the file since changing it (I forget that often).

If that doesn't unblock, share your file/code and that may help debug.